# SVG Matrix multiplication.How to equate two unequal matices

Tags: matrix, svg

I've two svg files.
File 1 :

```
  <g>                                                                                 
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="315 220;315 220"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" dur="5" keyTimes="0;1" type="scale" values="1,1;1,5"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="-315 -220;-315 -220"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="45 315 220;0 300 200"/>
    <rect x="300" y="200" width="30" height="40" fill="blue" />             
  </g>
```

File 2  :

```
  <g id="parent">                                                                                 
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="45 315 220;0 300 200"/>
    <rect id="child" x="300" y="200" width="30" height="40" fill="blue">                                                                              
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="315 220;315 220"/>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" dur="5" keyTimes="0;1" type="scale" values="1,1;1,5"/>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="-315 -220;-315 -220"/>               
    </rect>            
 </g>
```

As these two files have different animation because of multiplication of matrices.In File 1 we have T*S*(-T)*R and in File 2 we have R*T*S*(-T) .
My requirement is to make File 2 behave like File 1 .So I'll have to make some changes in File 2 matrix multiplication under a condition that **I can not touch animation of parent** .So what changes should I apply on **child** node ?I can not make changes outside of **child** node.So what ever I've to do that is inside **child** node.
Help me out of this ...

I want to give more obvious problem..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">
<svg baseProfile="tiny" display="inherit" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<symbol>
    <rect x="300" y="200" width="30" height="40" fill="yellow" opacity="0.5" id="symbol_0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="315 220;315 220"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" dur="5" keyTimes="0;1" type="scale" values="1,1;1,2"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="-315 -220;-315 -220"/>
    </rect>
</symbol>
<g id="anim1">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="315 220;315 220"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" dur="5" keyTimes="0;1" type="scale" values="1,1;1,5"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="-315 -220;-315 -220"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="45 315 220;0 300 200"/>

    <rect x="300" y="200" width="30" height="40" fill="blue" opacity="0.5" />
</g>
<g id="anim2">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="45 315 220;0 300 200"/>
    <use xlink:href="#symbol_0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="-45 315 220;0 300 200"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="315 220;315 220"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" dur="5" keyTimes="0;1" type="scale" values="1,1;1,2.5"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="translate" values="-315 -220;-315 -220"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"  additive="sum" begin="0"  fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" type="rotate" values="45 315 220;0 300 200"/> 
    </use>
</g>

<use id="N3" xlink:href="#symbol_0" x="100"/>
```

I don't want to change N3's animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have (2) and want it to behave like (1). From (2) we can read `R` but NOT rewrite it. From (2) we can generate (3) which is semantically equivalent to (1).

```
(1)  T*S*(-T)*R

(2)  R*T*S*(-T)

(3)  R*R^(-1)*T*S*(-T)*R
```

Since multiplicating R with its inverse gives us the identity matrix we can rewrite (2) in the following way which gives us (3):

- Read `R`
- calculate inverse of `R` => `R^(-1)`
- Insert `*R^(-1)` before `T`
- Append `*R`

You never mentioned javascript, so I included two solutions which solves this either by manual rewriting the script or by javascript.

Full solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/59Kjx/

Comment: Is there any other solution because there may be case when child node is used somewhere else in the same file ,suppose in Node N3 and because of adding two rotation nodes that N3's animation affects. I'm using javascript.

Comment: You can clone nodes with `myNode.cloneNode(true)` where `true` means it should be a deep clone, i.e. to also clone the descendant nodes and structure.